Minting Metaplex NFTs in an Anchor Program using PDAs
I am trying to mint Metaplex NFTs in an Anchor program. Unfortunately it seems that the provided seeds don't result in a valid address.
Here my program:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, web3} from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Factory } from "../target/types/factory";
import { PublicKey, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, Connection} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, createMint } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { assert } from "chai";  
const { SystemProgram } = web3;

describe("factory", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  console.log(`Connection: ${provider.connection.rpcEndpoint}`)

  const program = anchor.workspace.Factory as Program<Factory>;

  // Metaplex Constants
  const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");

  // Constants from our program
  const MINT_SEED = "mint";

  // Create keypairs for the payer and mint accounts
  const payer = Keypair.generate();
  const mint = Keypair.generate();

  it("Create an asset", async () => {

    // Airdrop SOL to payer for testing
    const airdropSignature = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 5e9);
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature, "confirmed");
    const balance = await provider.connection.getAccountInfo(payer.publicKey)
    console.log(`Balance for ${payer.publicKey}: ${balance.lamports/LAMPORTS_PER_SOL}`)

    // Create the InitTokenParams struct
      const token_params = {
        id: "1234",
        uri: "https://example.com/metadata.json", // Replace with your metadata URI
    };

    const [mintPDA, mintBump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from("mint"), 
        Buffer.from(token_params.id)
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    // Derive the metadata account PDA
    const [metadataPDA, metadataBump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from('metadata'),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintPDA.toBuffer(),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    // Derive the master edition PDA
    const [masterEditionPDA, masterEditionPDABump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from('metadata'),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintPDA.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from('edition'),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    console.log("Addresses")
    console.log(`provider account:              ${provider.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`payer account:                 ${payer.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`mint account:                  ${mint.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`Token Program:                 ${TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID}`)
    console.log(`System Program:                ${SystemProgram.programId}`)
    console.log(`mint PDA Program:              ${mintPDA}`)
    console.log(`master edition PDA Program:    ${masterEditionPDA}`)
    console.log(`metadata PDA Program:          ${metadataPDA}`)

    console.log("Bumps")
    console.log(`master edition PDA Bump:       ${masterEditionPDABump}`)
    console.log(`metadata PDA Bump:             ${metadataBump}`)
    // console.log(`metadataPDA account: ${metadataPDA}`)
    
    // Call the mint_nft function
    await program.methods
        .mintNft(token_params) // Call the function with the InitTokenParams struct
        .accounts({
            metadata: metadataPDA,
            masterEdition: masterEditionPDA,
            mint: mintPDA,
            payer: payer.publicKey,
            rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        })
        .signers([payer])
        .rpc();
  });
});


And my test script:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, web3} from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Factory } from "../target/types/factory";
import { PublicKey, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, Connection} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, createMint } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { assert } from "chai";  
const { SystemProgram } = web3;

describe("factory", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  console.log(`Connection: ${provider.connection.rpcEndpoint}`)

  const program = anchor.workspace.Factory as Program<Factory>;

  // Metaplex Constants
  const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");

  // Constants from our program
  const MINT_SEED = "mint";

  // Create keypairs for the payer and mint accounts
  const payer = Keypair.generate();
  const mint = Keypair.generate();

  it("Create an asset", async () => {

    // Airdrop SOL to payer for testing
    const airdropSignature = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 5e9);
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature, "confirmed");
    const balance = await provider.connection.getAccountInfo(payer.publicKey)
    console.log(`Balance for ${payer.publicKey}: ${balance.lamports/LAMPORTS_PER_SOL}`)

    // Create the InitTokenParams struct
      const token_params = {
        id: "1234",
        uri: "https://example.com/metadata.json", // Replace with your metadata URI
    };

    const [mintPDA, mintBump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from("mint"), 
        Buffer.from(token_params.id)
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    // Derive the metadata account PDA
    const [metadataPDA, metadataBump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from('metadata'),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintPDA.toBuffer(),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    // Derive the master edition PDA
    const [masterEditionPDA, masterEditionPDABump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from('metadata'),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintPDA.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from('edition'),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    console.log("Addresses")
    console.log(`provider account:              ${provider.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`payer account:                 ${payer.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`mint account:                  ${mint.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`Token Program:                 ${TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID}`)
    console.log(`System Program:                ${SystemProgram.programId}`)
    console.log(`mint PDA Program:              ${mintPDA}`)
    console.log(`master edition PDA Program:    ${masterEditionPDA}`)
    console.log(`metadata PDA Program:          ${metadataPDA}`)

    console.log("Bumps")
    console.log(`master edition PDA Bump:       ${masterEditionPDABump}`)
    console.log(`metadata PDA Bump:             ${metadataBump}`)
    // console.log(`metadataPDA account: ${metadataPDA}`)
    
    // Call the mint_nft function
    await program.methods
        .mintNft(token_params) // Call the function with the InitTokenParams struct
        .accounts({
            metadata: metadataPDA,
            masterEdition: masterEditionPDA,
            mint: mintPDA,
            payer: payer.publicKey,
            rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        })
        .signers([payer])
        .rpc();
  });
});

Here the error log:
  factory
Balance for CK1iJSdp6w4zWSkvGEE6eJsuYkvHEEPKLKveVpsQBegM: 5
Addresses
provider account:              EHbbJkVGh23Hd2GPcjZTMbror37MWF7tcfoyz5Ct2XRP
payer account:                 CK1iJSdp6w4zWSkvGEE6eJsuYkvHEEPKLKveVpsQBegM
mint account:                  DgxvxaJbXA1FadsiVnzjYA3ABnBDjCXRmhAsKceoBgmY
Token Program:                 TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
System Program:                11111111111111111111111111111111
mint PDA Program:              Dorw5wkcwaankrfC8u4sRtpwVNQ2aC6gXJXqSwQEFgHC
master edition PDA Program:    B5FrJNnvyN9ebAQbZL63gzLvMqfgPQUGsEZ3ZmYd8RXJ
metadata PDA Program:          EzKWoUop9uL5Tx7TMR9yBJZggxairLYosjRdhbkcK4D4
Bumps
master edition PDA Bump:       253
metadata PDA Bump:             255
    1) Create an asset


  0 passing (486ms)
  1 failing

  1) factory
       Create an asset:
     Error: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint2",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2780 of 187767 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program log: master_edition_id:    B5FrJNnvyN9ebAQbZL63gzLvMqfgPQUGsEZ3ZmYd8RXJ",
  "Program log: metadata_id:          EzKWoUop9uL5Tx7TMR9yBJZggxairLYosjRdhbkcK4D4",
  "Program log: master_edition_bump:    253",
  "Program log: metadata_bump:          255",
  "Program DwUgmXJmqnJqDcMuRE61AgbBSvfFY7gDmu6W55V7XPfd consumed 52924 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program DwUgmXJmqnJqDcMuRE61AgbBSvfFY7gDmu6W55V7XPfd failed: Could not create program address with signer seeds: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:6043:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5999:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:377:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:163:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Debugging I checked that the program was able to reconstruct correctly metadata pda and master edition pda (id and bump). I'm therefore sure that I am consifuring the right signers for invoke_signed. What I am doing wrong?
